# Bower Dependency Install Choice

Tags: bower

I have a package that I am building for use with bower that has a dependency of bootstrap. I know that some people prefer the LESS or SASS versions of bootstrap as opposed to the static version.

How do I, the package creator, offer the option to not install the static version of bootstrap when you install my bower package?

Comment: This is a great question. I'd love to hear the answer. As a developer, it's annoying when I choose to use bootstrap-sass-official, and I install a Bootstrap add-on that decides to download the LESS version of Bootstrap, which can often cause problems/collisions.